# A name for the automorphisms induced by the normalizer by conjugation?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, $H := \operatorname{N}\left( N \right)$ the normalizer of $N$. There is a natural morphism from $H$ to $\operatorname{Aut}\left( N \right)$ given by $h \mapsto \hat{h}$ where $\hat{h}\left( n \right)= h^{-1}nh$.

Is there a name in the literature for the image of this morphism or, equivalently, for the quotient $\frac{H}{\operatorname{C}_{H}\left( N \right)}$? Or for the elements in the image?

The specific context I'm interested in is that I'm studying the automorphism group, $\operatorname{Aut}$, of some structure, which has a normal subgroup $N$. Since I have information on the quotient $\frac{\operatorname{Aut}}{\operatorname{C}_{\operatorname{Aut}}\left( N \right)}$ I need to give a name to it. Any suggestion from analogous situations?

Comment: Aren't these just inner automorphisms?

Comment: An automorphism given by conjugation by an element is called the inner automorphism associated to that element (normally with a left/right convention adopted).

Comment: Inner automorphisms (of N) are a (usually proper) subgroup of the group I'm interested in.

Comment: @Michael I believe the point of this question is what they are called when viewed through $H$. The action of $N_G(H)$ on $H$ induces a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, and the question is "does this subgroup have a name"?

Comment: I should, however, say that I suspect that this subgroup is not well-defined. One could imagine a "twist" of $G$ by an automorphism which changes the action of the normaliser - that is, the twist is outside of the induced subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, but fixes $H$ setwise, so we are now looking at a different subgroup.